# Kendo treeview gives stack overflow error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using a kendo treeview with hierarchial datasource that gets the data from a remote call. I am expanding all nodes of the tree. Now for a bigger datasource (with say 70 + nodes), there is too much recursion happening. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: 70 nodes is a pretty small tree should not have problems. Are you sure that you are actually returning about 70 nodes?

Comment: i have create one example it has 100 nodes in it and its working fine please go through this link

http://jsfiddle.net/GHdwR/123/

Comment: Hi, I have the same feeling that its not too large but I still get the stack over flow error in IE8. For Firefox it doesnt show stackover flow,but if you examine in firebug, it shows too much recursion error. The issue happens only if I expand all nodes on load. I have added the .expand(".k-ite") in databound event of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by adding timeout while .expand(".k-item"). Looks like a timming issue in older browsers. Thanks to one of my collegue who pointed that out.

```
dataBound: function () {
                    setTimeout(function () { thiz.kendoTree.expand(".k-item"); }, 20);
                }
```

The time out value depends upon browser. Now that is not the best solution but atleast a work around.